# How to change the don't fragment (DF) flag for UDP packet in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, udp, mtu, ip-fragmentation

In Erlang, it is very simple to send `UDP` packet, that is to use `gen_udp:open()` to create a socket, then use `gen_udp:send()` to send out the data.

However, by default, the Linux `TCP/IP` stack will set the don't fragment (DF)flag in IP header if the size of IP packet doesn't exceed the MTU size. If the size exceeds the `MTU` size, the `UDP` packet will be fragmented.

Is there some way to not set DF flag for `UDP` packet only?

I know in C language, the following code could be used to clear the DF flag. But i couldn't find a way in Erlang.

```
int optval=0;
if(-1 == setsockopt(sockfd,IPPROTO_IP,IP_MTU_DISCOVER,&optval,sizeof(optval))) {
    printf("Error: setsockopt %d\n",errno);
    exit(1);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution after i posted this question :-(...:-)...

The solution is to set socket raw option by using `inet:setopts()` like what is done in C language, but the difference is that you need to know the definition of `IPPROTO_IP` and `IP_MTU_DISCOVER`.

The value of `IPPROTO_IP` is 0, defined in netinet/in.h
The value of `IP_MTU_DISCOVER` is 10, defined in linux/in.h

Below is example.
inet:setopts(Socket,[{raw,0,10,<<0:32/native>>}]).

I have tested it using small program, it is working.

You can find detail help for `inet:setopts` on erlang man page: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html

Thanks.